# My wordpress website is running very slowly on Xampp Localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I have been building an eshop website with woocommerce and i am using Zerif-Lite theme on Xampp Localhost. But it runs very slowly when i click a link, it needs like 5-7 seconds to load and on eshop page it needs 30 seconds(all products). What is the problem? Is this a localhost or theme issue? I also use wordfence Falcon engine cache. I have 27 active plugins. How can i fix that? If i upload the website to a live host will it be faster? I am optimizing my images with wp-smash. Do you suggest me disable Falcon engine cache and download w3 Total cache plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems running my localhost website from a usb, for me what turned it into a website with normal response times again was using UwAmp http://www.uwamp.com/en/?page=download. Also used a USB 3.0 Flash Drive, not sure how much difference that made.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use this free plugin called **P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)** which scans and give a detailed load-time for plugins,theme and DB, It is very useful and simple. you can find the plugin/theme/DB which is causing the issue and find  alternative for that.